# Determining a Laurent series with trigonometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I could use some help with the Laurent series around $z_{0}=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\{n\cdot\pi;\;n\in\mathbb{N}\} $ of the following function:
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{sin(z)}-cos(z)-z}{sin^{2}(z)} $$
In particular, I'm having problems trying to figure out the coefficients of the Laurent-Series and wether or not I can just use the respective Taylor or Fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s expand near $0$

$$\begin{align}
\sin{z}&=z-{z^3\over 6}+\cdots +(-1)^k{z^{2k+1}\over(2k+1)!}+\cdots\\
\cos{z}&=1-{z^2\over 2}+\cdots +(-1)^k{z^{2k}\over (2k)!}+\cdots
\end{align}$$

I cannot see a general expression for the general term but assume we want to expand to order $2$, one has

$$\begin{align}
\sin^2{z}&=\left(z-{z^3\over 6}\right)^2+o(z^4)=z^2-{z^4\over 3}+o(z^4)\\
e^{\sin{z}}&=1+ \left(z-{z^3\over 6}\right)+ {1\over 2}\left(z-{z^3\over 6}\right)^2+o(z^4)\\
&=1+z+{z^2\over 2}-{z^3\over 6}-{z^4\over 6}+o(z^4)\\
\cos{z}&=1-{z^2\over 2}+{z^4\over 24}+o(z^4)
\end{align}$$

Putting all the pieces together

$${e^{\sin{z}}-\cos{z}-z\over \sin^2{z}}={z^2-{z^3\over 6}-{5z^4\over 24}+o(z^4)\over z^2-{z^4\over 3}+o(z^4)}={1-{z\over 6}-{5z^2\over 24}+o(z^2)\over 1-{z^2\over 3}+o(z^2)}$$

Comment: As far as I can see, you are using the Taylor series in $0$. Assuming I would want to expand it near $\pi$, would I use the Taylor series expanded in $\pi$?

Comment: All functions considered are analytical in the whole plane so the series expansion (around $0$) is valid in the whole plane